# How to split text into new column within the same data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can I move the date into a new column within the same data frame

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Oasz.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can just split the column

```
df['New_Column'] = df.['Date Time'].apply(lambda x : str(x).split()[1])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
df['Date'] = df['Date Time'].str.split(' ').str[0]

# or

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time']).date
```